# How do I create an array of class pointers with new?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm a little bit confused.

I have this code:

```
class Fish {
public:
       void Swim()
       {
            std::cout << "I'm Swiming" << std::endl;
       }
};
```

Now, in another class, I want to do an aggregation of an array of this class:

```
class Pool {
     Fish ** fishes;
public:
     Pool(int p_fishes)
     {
         fishes = new Fish[p_fishes]
     }
     ~Pool()
     {
         delete[] fishes
     }
};
```

What I really want to do is to create an array of `Fish*` without being hard-coded like:

```
 Fish* fishes[8];
```

Is there any way to do this with `new`?

Comment: `new T[N]` its always the same just replace `T` with your type, but you should use `std::vector` or `std::array`, and why do you want an array of pointers?

Comment: After `fishes = new Fish[p_fishes]`, `fishes` points at an array of pointers to `Fish`. There are NO `Fish` created at this point. Often you need a loop to fill up the array of pointers. Note that doing this is "Stupid" in modern programming. It dramatically slows down the program because the CPU spends most of it's time looking up pointers and loading the data referenced by the pointer. If you have an array of `Fish` , not pointers to `Fish`, the processor doesn't have to go looking, and loading one `Fish` probably loads the next several `Fish` the algorithm is going to use at the same time.

Comment: @user4581301 `new Fish[p_fishes]` does not return an array of pointers. It returns array of fishes. Also I would let the author to finish his task first then optimize.

Comment: Side note: `Pool` does not observe the [Rule of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and this will result in the programs shooting itself repeatedly in the foot. Any time a class has to manage a resource, for example the allocation that's `new`ed and `delete`ed, the class also has to make sure the resource is copied correctly.

Comment: @DmytroOvdiienko Son of a <expletive deleted>. The mark I brain drew in an extra star to make the code compile. I stand corrected.

Comment: `class Pool { std::vector<Fish> fishes..` -- Any reason why you are not simply doing this?

Comment: An array of `Fish*` pointers makes sense if there are other classes derived from `Fish` that need to be put into the array

Comment: Lucas, I think you need to describe the problem you're trying to solve better. We can give answers that will do exactly what we THINK you want to do, but many of those will be useless to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Fish* fishes[...];` is a fixed-length array holding `Fish*` *pointers*.

`new Fish[...]` is a dynamic-length array holding `Fish` *objects*.

In general, `new T[N]` returns a `T*` pointer to an array of `N` number of `T` objects.

In your case, `T` is `Fish`, so `new Fish[]` returns a `Fish*` pointer. You can't assign a `Fish*` pointer to a `Fish**` pointer, like you are trying to do.

If you really want an array of `Fish*` pointers, you need to use `new Fish*[...]` instead, which returns a `Fish**` pointer that you are looking for, eg:

```
class Pool {
     Fish ** fishes;
     int num_fishes;
public:
     Pool(int p_fishes)
     {
         num_fishes = p_fishes;
         fishes = new Fish*[p_fishes];
         for(int i = 0; i < p_fishes; ++i) {
             fishes[i] = new Fish;
         }
     }

     ~Pool()
     {
         for(int i = 0; i < num_fishes; ++i) {
             delete fishes[i];
         }
         delete[] fishes
     }
};
```

Note: this is just an example to answer your specific question. This is NOT the kind of code you should be writing in general. For instance, `Pool` as shown does not follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), and is also not exception-safe. Consider using `std::vector<Fish>` instead.

Comment: Suggest showing the use of a member initialization list in the constructor.

Comment: suggest to delete copies or properly implement rule of 3

Answer (score 0):

Its always the same: `new T[N]` dynamically allocates an array of `N` elements of type `T`. Using the member initializer list you would do this:

```
 Pool(int p_fishes) : fishes(new Fish * [p_fishes]) 
 {}
```

However, this will make your `Pool` a) rather boring, because it does not contain any fish, it only contains pointers. b) broken, because it does not follow the rule of 3, copying it will get you two `Pool` that share the same array of pointers (that they both will delete in their destructor).

If you want `Pool` to be an "aggregation of an array of this class" use `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Fish {
public:
       void Swim()
       {
            std::cout << "I'm Swiming" << std::endl;
       }
};

class Pool {
     std::vector<Fish> fishes;
public:
     Pool(int p_fishes) : fishes(p_fishes) 
     {
        std::cout << "I am a pool with " << fishes.size() << " default constructed fishes.\n";
     }
};

int main() {
    Pool p(42);
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/bK4cY58Mb):

```
I am a pool with 42 default constructed fishes.
```

For further reading I suggest [What is The Rule of Three?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/4117728) (dont miss to read the part that talks about the rule of 0).